# Nginx: Bypass host SSL connection for one server only on reverse proxy setup

Tags: nginx

I have a Nginx reverse proxy setup.  I wish to allow one of my servers to take care of it's own SSL but still be controlled via a host with a reverse proxy setup.

Basically I am trying to reopen this question as it is almost 6-years old with no solution:  [nginx: forward ssl connection to another server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33268092/nginx-forward-ssl-connection-to-another-server)

I have seen some info about possible streams?

Is it still not possible to do this?  Or is there now a solution?

[image]

Most of my servers are set up like this in the host (reverse proxy server):

```
server {
    if ($host = my.coolsite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


 server_name my.coolsite.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}



server {

 server_name my.coolsite.com;
      location / {

                 ## Set Headers
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
                client_max_body_size 5M;
                proxy_pass http://192.168.1.12;
                proxy_redirect off;
}


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.coolsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.coolsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
```

Can I have one server take care of its own ssl?

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of googling it seems HAProxy, instead of Nginx, might be a better solution for my needs...